# How to calculate the difference of the values in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, difference

I have a dictionary that looks like this (whitespaces for clarity):

```
dic={'848613': [-0.22307240991541583, -0.46447953845401646, -0.1864029726690461, 
                -0.17906908521977213, -0.22246125262797634, -0.09472937955312179,
                -0.2884662396714418, -0.3703613161883342],
     '820434': [-0.09142433555202074, -0.15535959723873796, -0.1402251633128967,
                -0.2680956866863311, -0.2226923849088073, -0.28353898661065896, 
                -0.1501088752644665, -0.17976001111917592],
     '846353': [0.12422057244522786, 0.1500662052036628, 0.15781989503119326,
                0.176881049190539, 0.17090424661515094, 0.13956641689554858, 
                0.11129775606601039, 0.0794753207321874]}
```

I want to calculate the difference between two values in the same key, for example, the difference between the first two values is 0.241407128539. The code I used so far is:

```
x=[]
z=[]
l=0

for a in dic:
    x.append(dic[a])
y=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))
a=0
b=1
d=len(y)-1
for c in range(d):
    z.append(y[a]-y[b])
    a+=1
    b+=1
print z
```

However, this code continues when all the values of one key have been used and combines them with the next one. This way it also calculates the difference between the last value of a key and the first value of the next one.
Is there a nice way to solve this or do I have to cut out all the wrong numbers?

Comment: What's wrong with `x, y = dic.values(), dic.keys()`? Why the looping and `itertools` use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your code *tremendously*. If you want to subtract the first two values of each list, then just loop directly over the dictionary items:

```
for key, values in dic.iteritems():
    print key, values[0] - values[1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> dic={'848613': [-0.22307240991541583, -0.46447953845401646, -0.1864029726690461, 
...                 -0.17906908521977213, -0.22246125262797634, -0.09472937955312179,
...                 -0.2884662396714418, -0.3703613161883342],
...      '820434': [-0.09142433555202074, -0.15535959723873796, -0.1402251633128967,
...                 -0.2680956866863311, -0.2226923849088073, -0.28353898661065896, 
...                 -0.1501088752644665, -0.17976001111917592],
...      '846353': [0.12422057244522786, 0.1500662052036628, 0.15781989503119326,
...                 0.176881049190539, 0.17090424661515094, 0.13956641689554858, 
...                 0.11129775606601039, 0.0794753207321874]}
>>> 
>>> for key, values in dic.iteritems():
...     print key, values[0] - values[1]
... 
848613 0.241407128539
820434 0.0639352616867
846353 -0.0258456327584
```

Comment: Well, this is a lot easier indeed, thank you. I am quite new to programming and this struck me as the only possible way, but thanks to you my code is a lot better.